# AngularJS expression checking child properties in a list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I write an angular expression that checks each child item in a list and returns true if any child has a certain property value?

I have a chart legend being generated by an ng-repeat expression. Now I want to show the wrapping element only if any of the child items in the list has the property "datavisible" set to true.

Currently I have a $scope variable "anydatavisible" being set to true if any of the data series is activated so I can use that in an expression.

```
<div class="chart-legend" ng-show="anydatavisible">
    <div ng-repeat="item in model.Accounts track by item.Id" ng-if="item.datavisible">
        {{item.Name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I was wondering I can get the same result by using an expression that checks each child so I don't have the need for the variable "$scope.anydatavisible".

I'm looking for something like this:

```
<div class="chart-legend" ng-show="any(model.Accounts).datavisible">
    <div ng-repeat="item in model.Accounts track by item.Id" ng-if="item.datavisible">
        {{item.Name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Create a custom filter and attach it to the ng-repeat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="chart-legend" ng-show="(model.Accounts | filter:{datavisible:true}).length > 0">
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work after all. Getting a syntax error: Syntax Error: Token '' {1} at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].

Comment: correct, forgot you cant declare a function in an expression. try the update (based on the previous answer)